# Vue.js v-for for server generated html list data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

We can use the v-for directive to render a list of items based on an array.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
    {{ item.message }}
  </li>
</ul>

var list = new Vue({
  el: '#list',
  data: {
    items: [
      { message: 'Red' },
      { message: 'Blue' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Everything works good when we try to render data from the client. But if there any option to start with already generated by the server html list (because of SEO and many other reasons), and then continue to manage it in a "classic" Vue.js way?

Our server generates some init data:

```
<script>
    list.items = [{"message": "Red"}, {"message": "Blue"}];
</script>

<ul id="list">
    <li>
       Red
    </li>
    <li>
       Blue
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't understand how you mean. Would it not be the same to have `v-for="item in list.items"`?

Comment: I mean that the list come ready (generated) from backend, to be visible for search engines. After it i start to manage It  from a client

Comment: Oh I see how you mean. I think you could probably render it as static HTML but having it available to alter with Vue wouldn't work. Vue needs to build the files for production so to have ready-made HTML from the server that you could then use `v-for` with, for example, isn't doable. Sounds more like something you'd be better off using Nuxt for

Comment: Thx for that advice. Nuxt looks interesting, but I have a Golang based web server which generates html pages, lists and etc (depends on grants), and It is not a good solution (for my current architecture of course) to create an another one layer between my server and enduser. So as I see, It is impossible to do with Vue.js.

Comment: Can't you generate the list from the HTML in client side and re-render it with Vue ?